# How can I access my req.body data/json in Express?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am new to node.js and I am trying to access json on my node.js server from a post request so I can send it to an API and feed it back to my front-end js file. I can see the json object, but I can't seem to access it(ex: req.body.name) after reading some documentation/stackoverflow posts.

Here is my post route from my server.js file, and packages:

```
    var prettyjson = require('prettyjson');
    var express = require('express');
    var http = require('http');
    var cors = require('cors');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var app = express();


    // create application/json parser 
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    // create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser 
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));

    app.post('/', function(req, res) {

    var test = req.body; //If I req.body.name here, it will return undefined
    console.log(test);

    });
```

Here is my front end map.js file post function and data:

```
  var locations = [
  {name:'Le Thai', coords:{lat:36.168743, lng:-115.139866}},
  {name:'Atomic Liquors', coords:{lat:36.166782, lng:-115.13551}},
  {name:'The Griffin', coords:{lat:36.168785, lng:-115.140329}},
  {name:'Pizza Rock', coords:{lat:36.17182, lng:-115.142304}},
  {name:'Mob Museum', coords:{lat:36.172815,lng:-115.141242}},
  {name:'Joe Vicari’s Andiamo Italian Steakhouse', coords:{lat:36.169437, lng:-115.142903}},
  {name:'eat', coords:{lat:36.166535, lng:-115.139067}},
  {name:'Hugo’s Cellar', coords:{lat:36.169915, lng:-115.143861}},
  {name:'Therapy', coords:{lat:36.169041, lng:-115.139829}},
  {name:'Vegenation', coords:{lat:36.167401, lng:-115.139453}}

  ];
   //convert array to JSON 
   var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(locations);

   $.post('http://localhost:3000/', jsonStr, function(data){
     //empty for now

   },'json');
```

End goal: I want to be able to access my data like req.body.name. I tried using typeof on req.body, and it returns an object, however I can't seem to access this object. And I tried using JSON.parse, but realized req.body is already an object. I would like to serve this data to the Yelp API eventually.

Current output(per request) from console.log(req.body):

```
{ '{"name":"Le Thai","coords":{"lat":36.168743,"lng":-115.139866}},
{"name":"Atomic Liquors","coords":{"lat":36.166782,"lng":-115.13551}},
{"name":"The Griffin","coords":{"lat":36.168785,"lng":-115.140329}},
{"name":"Pizza Rock","coords":{"lat":36.17182,"lng":-115.142304}},
{"name":"Mob Museum","coords":{"lat":36.172815,"lng":-115.141242}},
{"name":"Joe Vicari’s Andiamo Italian Steakhouse","coords":
{"lat":36.169437,"lng":-115.142903}},{"name":"eat","coords":
{"lat":36.166535,"lng":-115.139067}},{"name":"Hugo’s Cellar","coords":
{"lat":36.169915,"lng":-115.143861}},{"name":"Therapy","coords":
{"lat":36.169041,"lng":-115.139829}},{"name":"Vegenation","coords":
{"lat":36.167401,"lng":-115.139453}}': '' }
```

Comment: req.body.locations[index].name?

Comment: @leo `locations` isn't part of the data :)

Comment: hahaha, sorry...

Comment: Congrats on getting started! One of the first things you'll want to do is learn to use `node-inspector` or one of the other debuggers available for Node. That way, you can set a breakpoint on the `req.body` line and look around, expanding the values of variables and such. Using a debugger is like turning on the lights in a dark room. It's not an advanced skill, it's critical for beginners to learn it early. Enjoy!

Comment: Side note: The `dataType` parameter on `$.post` **isn't** to tell the server what you're sending it, it's to tell jQuery what you're expecting back from the server. To tell the server what you're sending it (which is important), use `$.ajax` and the `contentType` option.

Comment: Turns out my note about `dataType` above isn't a side note, it's central to the problem. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're not telling the server you're sending it JSON, so it's not getting parsed. Also, as [rsp pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43345792/157247), to access the first name, you'd want `req.body[0].name`, not `req.body.name`.

The `dataType` parameter on `$.post` isn't to tell the server what *you're* sending *it*, it's to tell jQuery what you're expecting *back* from the server. To tell the server what you're sending it, use `$.ajax` and the `contentType` option:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",  // <====
    data: jsonStr,
    success: function(data){
     //empty for now
    }
});
```

Now, the `body-parser` module sees the content type on the request, and parses it for you. So for instance, if I change your server file to do this:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    req.body.forEach(function(entry, index) {
        console.log(index, entry.name)
    });
});
```

...then with the change above to the client code, I get this on the server console:

```
0 'Le Thai'
1 'Atomic Liquors'
2 'The Griffin'
3 'Pizza Rock'
4 'Mob Museum'
5 'Joe Vicari’s Andiamo Italian Steakhouse'
6 'eat'
7 'Hugo’s Cellar'
8 'Therapy'
9 'Vegenation'
```

Comment: so I was right in parsing the data at the backend, but thanks for letting me know that I can do automatically by setting `content-type: JSON` initially also I mentioned of parsing because I also faced the same issue.

Comment: @warl0ck: The server-side parser was there, just not being triggered, right.

Answer (score 4):

You're using an array, so it will not be:

```
req.body.name
```

but e.g.

```
req.body[0].name
```

You probably want to iterate over the array that you get with `.forEach` or a `for` loop etc.

Comment: When I do console.log(req.body[0].name), I am seeing: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: thats because you have not parsed it yet into JSON

Comment: @warl0ck: See the OP's code: `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: That's another issue I ran into. When I do: 'var test = JSON.parse(req.body);
console.log(test);' , I get an error: "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Comment: my bad @dream_cap i didnt see bodyparser being used in

Comment: @Dream_Cap: You really need to use the debugger to look at `req.body`. (Or you could just do `console.log(req.body)`, but that's using a torch rather than turning on the lights.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the information. I am currently in search of one. The node-inspector you mentioned said it deprecated  recently, but I'm sure there's a tool out there. I definitely need to learn breakpoints.

Comment: @Dream_Cap what the output you are getting when you simply do `console.log(req.body);`

Comment: @warl0ck I added the output in the main post just now, the comment section said the json was too big for it.

Comment: @Dream_Cap: The question's the right place for it anyway. :-)

Comment: @Dream_Cap: *"I am currently in search of one. The node-inspector you mentioned said it deprecated recently"* I was initially dismayed to read that, but it's actually good news, it's only deprecated because [Node has it built in now](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27). Yay! Thanks for letting me know (been a few months since my last Node-based project).

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. I was trying to debug for this hours. I did think the $.post method was a bit suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

For those getting an empty object in req.body

I had forgotten to set  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"} in the request. Changing it solved the problem